# JBoss 7.1.1.Final - accessing WS from remote address

Tags: linux, web-services, rest, centos, jboss7.x

Connecting to WS from remote host doesn't work while from localhost works fine.

I opened ports 8080 and 8443 as found here: 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-open-ports/

In standalone.xml I added public interface with  to http/https connectors and/or started jboss with "-b 0.0.0.0" but nothing helps. Connection always time outs.

I'm using JBoss 7.1.1.Final.